# Redirect after creation of Entry in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, redirect

I want to redirect to the view of what I just entered in my article. But it seems id is not available somehow...

```
if ($this->Articles->save($data, array('deep' => true))) {
                                $current_id = $this->Articles->id;
                                return $this->redirect(['controller'=> 'articles', 'action' => 'view', $current_id]);                
                            }
```

I just get **502 Bad Gateway**
 Sometimes also:

*Table "App\Model\Table\ArticlesTable" is not associated with "id"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently you have to save the save function in a variable. Then it works:

```
if ($this->Articles->save($tmp = $data, array('deep' => true))) {
                                $current_id = $tmp->id;
                                return $this->redirect(['controller'=> 'articles', 'action' => 'view', $current_id]);                
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think right code is

```
$article= $this->Articles->newEntity($data);
if ($this->Articles->save($article, array('deep' => true))) {
    $current_id = $article->id;
    return $this->redirect(['controller'=> 'articles', 'action' => 'view', $current_id]);
}
```